# How to sum rows with similar names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

[image]

Each row has its own copy with the 'treatment_group' prefix but with a different coefficient.
How can I sum these rows by coef across the entire dataframe using the following logic: sum = treatment_group: feature 19 + feature 19?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to sum every instance of ```treatment_group: feature X``` with its corresponding ```feature X``` ?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: or simply `df.groupby(df.index.str.extract('(\d+)$')).sum()` to match just the trailing numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split` with select last value, it working for any values with aggregate `sum`:

```
df.groupby(df.index.str.split(':').str[-1]).sum()
```

Or use `replace`:

```
df.groupby(df.index.str.replace('treatment_group:', '', regex=True)).sum()
```

Like mentioned @mozway in comments - is possible extract last numbers in index (added `expand=False` for return `Series`):

```
df.groupby(df.index.str.extract('(\d+)$', expand=False)).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
df.groupby(df.index.str.extract('(\d+)$')).sum()
```

Comment: What does the $ sign do?

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi Oh, that gets from the end of the string.